# Can't open 2 URLs (or more) in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So Chrome has the crazy kerjigger that makes JavaScript safe for users. It makes sense, and I'm trying to make a program that can save bookmarks and open them all at once for learning purposes and personal usage :). I have the following code yet it only opens the first link.

popup.js:

```
window.open("https://www.google.com");
window.open("https://www.twitter.com")
```

popup.html:

```
<script src = "popup.js"/>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "SpeedyURLs",
"icons":
{
"19": "icon.png",
"128": "icon2.png"
},
"description": "This is a mass bookmark extension allowing you to open multiple bookmarks at once!",
"version": "0.1",

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
"activeTab",
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
]

}
```

It works in JSFiddle and browser, and I'm pretty sure Chrome is preventing the code from running. Any ideas?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create

Comment: Could you please provide more codes about your extension? It works well at my end. And what's you manifest.json and where did you call these two methods?

Comment: Oh... My code in popup.html references popup.js and only does that. It has two logos one for the thumbnail and one for chrome://extensions. The manifest will be added on my question